# Java opening files - works from Eclipse, doesn't work in runnable JAR/exe

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, explorer

I have some java code that I'm using to open a file:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + output.getAbsolutePath());
```

It works just fine when I execute it from Eclipse, however, when I export the project to a runnable JAR, the functionality stops working. I've tried various different options to open the file (Desktop.open, ProcessBuilder etc.) all with the same results (Eclipse OK, runnable JAR not).

This exact code previously worked when I exported it in the past (1.5 years ago). I believe that was with Java 1.6 and now we're on Java 1.7. Not sure if that's the reason though and I don't have the option to compile using previous versions of Java. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the exceptions you get if it's possible?

Comment: Are you running it on the same machine?

Comment: I would avoid using the dll completely: Java is run anywhere, this way you are bound to MS Windows and possibly even a version of that to actually see it work.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that assigns a value to `output`.  If you’re calling Class.getResource or ClassLoader.getResource and calling getFile() on the returned URL, it will never work, both because getFile() does not convert a URL to a file and because a .jar file is a zip archive and its entries are not actual files, just subsequences of compressed bytes.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for attempting to help. I figured out the answer which is quite simply that I'm an idiot :) Opening the file wasn't the problem, the file wasn't being written in the first place, and the reason it wasn't being written was quite simply because the code was set to write it into a nested folder structure which had not yet been created. I didn't even think of this because I assumed that any necessary folders specified in the output string would be created automatically. Doh!